# Print table with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, printing, scroll

I have to print a table with horizontal scroll and I need to print everything. The thing is that when te code does "Window.Print()" it cuts my page and doesn't show all the info of the table. I really need your help!! I need to "cut" my table and put it below if it doesn't fit the page.

(i can't put a fixed value width to the table because i don't know how much columns i might have, it can be like 2 or 50)

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Do you have access to the code that generates the html page?  If so that's where you need to generate a printer-friendly page dynamically as tehMick suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a particularly good solution for this.  Printing HTML tables is usually problematic.  Consider making a printer-friendly version where you cut the table programmatically into groups of columns that make sense together.  You may need to repeat columns that uniquely identify each row.  Proper CSS can help your table to fit to the width of the page.  I can't think of another way to do it that really outputs a very usable table.

Comment: i really can't re-fit my table because i don't know how much columns it might have.. it's dinamic. Besides i can have like 2 columns or 50 so its impossible por me to adapt the table to the width of the page!

Comment: Well, you could cut it dynamically as well.  Set it to a maximum of maybe 10 columns per page and give each cell a width of *.